# Fatal error when cloning a project from github: ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a public project from GitHub. I am facing a fatal error as

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/mrvautin/expressCart.git/': error:1408F10B:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

If someone canhelp me with this?

Comment: What version of git do you have, and with what OS?

Comment: git version 2.21.0.windows.10

Comment: The previous answered question could not solve my problem

Comment: It's the same question though sadly.